# Is it possible to Dynamically Create a Class with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm creating a library and in this library, It will contain Shapes more precisely Regular and Irregular Polygons, this library must allow the users to not only use my shapes but also in runtime be able to create his own.

At the moment I have a few shapes provided like so:

```
Polygon
|- PolygonRegular
   |- Square
   |- Circle
   |- EquilateralTriangle implements Triangle
|- PolygonIrregular
   |- Trapeze
   |- IsoscelesTriangle implements Triangle
```

Now in this given scenario, let's say I as a user want to create my custom Polygon in this case "ScaleneTriangle" in which will further also implement the Triangle interface, my library must easily provide the tools necessary to create this "factory" to create shapes.

```
  //Though I don't know the code, what I wanted to achieve, would be something very close to:

    Point2D[] points = new Point2D[]{
            new Point2D.Float(0f, 0f),
            new Point2D.Float(0.25f, 0f),
            new Point2D.Float(1f, 1f),
    };

    ContentFactory.create(PolygonIrregular.class, "ScaleneTriangle", points);
```

However, I have no idea How can I make a ContentFactory just like this, that create classes in runtime just like it was magic... I will also magically gonna have to create instances of these classes too.

To give about more understanding in case the problem wasn't very clarified:
Imagine I'm a user, a canvas pop, draw a new shape. Confirms. A buttonRepresentation is created whit this new shape. Every time the user clicks in buttonRepresentation an element is created whit the shape.

Comment: Have you looked into using [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/)?

Comment: If possible i would prefer to do it using plain java.

Comment: It is possible to create your own java code and compile it at runtime using [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) implementations. Then you would have to load bytecode of compiled class at runtime and inovke methods via reflection.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the *Javadoc?* `Class.newInstance()` for example? No external libraries required.

Comment: The problem whit that is you need a class:3 If you don't have the receipt(class) you can't create cakes(instances). What I really want is to be able to create receipts and not cakes, JavaCompiler seems promising.

Comment: Why do you model different types of polygons as classes? They do not seem to behave polymorphous. Getting the points of the polygon is monomorphous. And each property could also be stored in a list of polygon properties (as field of the generic class). I cannot imagin a polymorphous method that all polygon classes have in common (and that satisfies the liskov substitution principle).

Comment: Well, the easier way to explain would be to open powerpoint preference 365. Draw one of those big arrows. This shape would have custom properties like arrow length and arrow size. Using "triangle" implements that I mention briefly could hold some exclusive behavior. (If u draw a triangle in powerpoint u can move the top angle). I hate soo much powerpoint, lol.

Comment: @JoãoMarques If you don't have a class you can't do reflection on it. This seems obvious. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

In [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and), it is done using jOOQ, but you can re implement their method if you don't want an extra dependency. ([archive for posterity](https://web.archive.org/web/20190413114613/https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and))

The way that I have done it in the past (just as a test), was to use a compiler from janino to compile a string to a class which implements an interface which is known at compile time. It's in kotlin, but it would be easy to convert to Java.

```
package com.dmercer

import org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler;
import org.codehaus.janino.util.Benchmark

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val sourceString = """
package com.dmercer;

public class B implements BasicInterface {
    @Override
    public void runMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello from compiled method");
    }
}
    """.trimIndent()

    val compiler = SimpleCompiler()
    compiler.cook(sourceString)
    val classLoader = compiler.classLoader
    val compiledClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.dmercer.B")// as IDBMethod
    val classInstance = compiledClass.newInstance() as BasicInterface 
    classInstance.runMethod()

}
```

Comment: I was able to pull it off whit JavaCompiler. I will still mark it as correct since most stuff I did whit compiler seems in your code.

Comment: Excellent. It would be good if you could post the essential part of your solution if you can, for any future user who comes across this.